# Oracle Analytical Function?

Tags: sql, oracle18c, analytical

For the given table below, how can we find the customer whose name appears 3 times consecutively.

```
+---------+-----------+
| CUST_ID | CUST_NAME |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | SAM       |
+---------+-----------+
| 2       | SAM       |
+---------+-----------+
| 3       | SAM       |
+---------+-----------+
| 4       | PETER     |
+---------+-----------+
| 5       | PETER     |
+---------+-----------+
```

Desired_Output

```
+-----------+
| CUST_NAME |
+-----------+
| SAM       |
+-----------+
```

Table Definition:

```
create table Customer
(
  cust_id int,
  cust_name varchar2(20)
);

insert into customer values (1, 'SAM');
insert into customer values (2, 'SAM');
insert into customer values (3, 'SAM');
insert into customer values (4, 'PETER');
insert into customer values (5, 'PETER');
```

Code Tried so far

```
Select distinct cust_name from (
select
cust_id,
cust_name,
lag(cust_name,1,0) over (order by cust_id)  as prev_cust_name,
lead(cust_name,1,0) over (order by cust_id) as next_cust_name
 from customer) a
 where a.prev_cust_name=a.next_cust_name;
```

I believe we can do this by using lead/lag to get the previous and next row. Although my solution gives the desired output but i don't think this is correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is close.  You need one more comparison:

```
select distinct cust_name 
from (select c.*
             lag(cust_name) over (order by cust_id)  as prev_cust_name,
             lead(cust_name) over (order by cust_id) as next_cust_name
      from customer c
     ) a c
where prev_cust_name = cust_name and cust_name = next_cust_name;
```

For a more general solution, you can compare two lags:

```
select distinct cust_name 
from (select c.*
             lag(cust_id, 2) over (order by cust_id)  as prev2_cust_id,
             lag(cust_id, 2) over (partitioin by name order by cust_id)  as prev2_cust_id_name
      from customer c
     ) a c
where prev2_cust_id = prev2_cust_id_name;
```

This looks two rows back -- once only by `cust_id` and once only for the name.  If the `cust_id` values are the same, then all rows have the same name.  You can adjust `2` to any value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find `N` consecutive values you can use window functions. See example for N = 4:

```
with params (n) as (select 4 from dual) -- Set N = 4
select distinct cust_name
from (
  select
    cust_id, cust_name, n,
    min(cust_name) over 
      (order by cust_id rows between n - 1 preceding and current row) as mi,
    max(cust_name) over
      (order by cust_id rows between n - 1 preceding and current row) as ma,
    count(*) over
      (order by cust_id rows between n - 1 preceding and current row) as cnt
  from customer
  cross join params
) x
where mi = ma and cnt = n
```

See running example at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8dbba/3).